# How to remove black edge on UIImageView with rounded corners and a border width?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, quartz-graphics

I have the following code to make the `UIImageView` in each of my UITableView's cells have rounded corners:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Rounded corners.
    [[cellImage layer] setCornerRadius:([cellImage frame].size.height / 2)];
    [[cellImage layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [[cellImage layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [[cellImage layer] setBorderWidth:3]; // Trouble!
}
```

I want the images to have a bit of a gap between them, and figured I could make use of the border width to make that happen. Below is an image of what actually happened:

[image: list of users with badly rendered rounded corners]

It's that faint black border that I want to know how to get rid of. I'd like to think there's a way of doing it using border width. If not, the best approach might be just to resize the image itself and just set the border width to be 0.

Comment: Why you set border with at all?

Comment: To get a gap between the images, otherwise their top and bottom edges touch

Comment: How about  setting :- [[cellImage layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];?

Comment: Then just make your imageView a little bit smaller instead of setting border width

Comment: You can decrease the imageview width and height in 6 px to achieve that gap.

Comment: Nov 2017, this is still not fixed. iOS 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using corner radius, you can create bezier path for the mask, create a shape layer for that path, and then specify that shape layer for the image view's layer's mask:

```
CGFloat margin = 3.0;
CGRect rect = CGRectInset(imageView.bounds, margin, margin);
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(imageView.bounds.size.width/2, imageView.bounds.size.height/2) radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO];
CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.path = path.CGPath;
imageView.layer.mask = mask;
```

Comment: Although this works, I recommend using `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(imageView.bounds.size.width/2 ,imageView.bounds.size.height/2) radius:radius startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI*2 clockwise:NO]` instead of `bezierPathWithOvalInRect:`, as it makes a true circular shape (you can notice some angles using the latter).

Comment: Not working when there is another background below imageviews rather than white. It showing that background instead of white. any suggestions to solve?

Comment: Hi @Rob, I figure out the way. will post new answer with merge of your code. Will help developers to solve.

Answer (score -2):

*What you are doing is, you are clipping the profile image and the border together, which is making the cell's profile image extending through the border.*

**You are missing this line:-**

```
cellImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: The `layer` doesn't have the `clipsToBounds` property.

Comment: Thanks @MattPotts for rectifying, I was in  hurry   ;-)